# Perl Adding two regex in the same time

Tags: perl

Its for perl script, I want to put two regex into same pattern attribute .First regex should enter 
digit number {2,4} two or four same at the next range.

exmaple white space 1 1111 123

example with vertical bar ( | ) 1|1111|123

Here's the regex for white space only work fine

```
if($msg{'what'} =~ /\cmd\s(\d{2,4})\s(\d{4,6})\s(\d{3,4})/)
```

with two pattern \s and | its not working.

```
if($msg{'what'} =~ /\cmd\s(\d{2,4})\s?\|(\d{4,6})\s?\|(\d{3,4})/)
```

desired output is to get result with a space or a vertical bar in one line regex.

1|1111|123 or 1 1111 123

Comment: Do you mean "separated by either a space or a vertical bar character"?

Comment: Please give several sample inputs and the desired results.

Comment: tadman Yes 
Yunnosch  results its like the example 1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex

```perl
/(\d{1,4})\s?\|(\d{4,6})\s?\|(\d{3,4})/)
```

looks for an optional space and then a pipe, i.e., there must be a pipe for the regex to match. If you want either pipe or white space, use a [bracketed character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes) of the two `[\s|]`:

```
/(\d{1,4})[\s|](\d{4,6})[\s|](\d{3,4})/)
```

Because it's a bracketed character class, you also don't need to escape the pipe symbol.

Note though that your example inputs don't fit the regex you posted; in particular, your examples don't have a "cmd" prefix and they only start with one leading digit, not 2 to 4, as your regex expects. I've adjusted the regex here to match the example input.

```
robert@saaz:~$ echo 1 1111 123 | perl -ne 'print "matches\n" if (m/(\d{1,4})[\s|](\d{4,6})[\s|](\d{3,4})/);' 
matches

robert@saaz:~$ echo '1|1111|123' | perl -ne 'print "matches\n" if (m/(\d{1,4})[\s|](\d{4,6})[\s|](\d{3,4})/);' 
matches
```

Comment: Thanks what if i want to add another | like this
'1|11|11|123'

Comment: You just put that in the regex, just repeat `\d{1-4}[\s|]` for as many groups as you need. Just make sure to not end the regex  with `[\s|]` or it will only match when the input ends in `|` or space.

Comment: Robert i did but not working 
(\d{1,4})[\s|](\d{4,6})[\s|](\d{4,6})[\s|](\d{3,4})
i'm using regex101.com for testing.

Comment: @DrJay Your regex calls for 4 to 6 digits, but your input has only 2 (between the pipes).